# .NET WCF Activator for sync and async calls

Tags: c#, asynchronous, delegates, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I decided to re-write my code responsible for WCF calls, as all of my methods had `try`-`catch`-`finally` blocks. I read that it is bad idea to use a `using()` statement as it does not close the WCF connection. After digging around, I found a solution based on delegates. Yesterday I decided to add an activator for calls that are made by async controllers in my MVC Web API app.

I am not sure about the code used for async. My doubts are based on [this article](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html).

Note - some code removed for brevity.

**Here is the code for activators:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace MyProject.Concrete
{
    public class SvcActivator<T>
    {
        public delegate void ServiceMethod(T proxy);

        private BasicHttpBinding binding
        {
            get
            {
                return new BasicHttpBinding
                {
                    MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
                    MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue
                };
            }
        }

        public static void Use(ServiceMethod method, string url)
        {
            var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>(binding);
            var endpoit = new EndpointAddress(url);
            IClientChannel proxy = (IClientChannel)channelFactory.CreateChannel(endpoit);
            bool success = false;

            try
            {
                method((T)proxy);
                proxy.Close();
                success = true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (!success)
                {
                    proxy.Abort();
                }
            }
        }

        public static Task UseAsync(ServiceMethod method, string url, HttpBindingBase binding)
        {
            var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>(binding);
            var endpoit = new EndpointAddress(url);
            IClientChannel proxy = (IClientChannel)channelFactory.CreateChannel(endpoit);
            bool success = false;

            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    method((T)proxy);
                    proxy.Close();
                    success = true;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (!success)
                    {
                        proxy.Abort();
                    }
                }
            });
        }    
    }
}
```

**Here is sample DAL:**

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using MyProject.OrdersService;

namespace MyProject.Concrete
{
    public class OrdersDAL : CommonDAL
    {
        public Order GetOrder(int id)
        {
            Order order = null;
            SvcActivator<IOrdersService>.Use(svc =>
            {
                order = svc.GetOrder(id);
            }, "url_goes_here");
            return order;
        }

        public async Task<Order> GetOrderAsync(int id)
        {
            Order order = null;
            await SvcActivator<IOrdersService>.UseAsync(svc =>
            {
                order = svc.GetOrder(id);
            }, "url_goes_here");
            return order;
        }
    }
}
```

**And finally, here is sample API controller:**

```
namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    public class OrdersController : CommonController
    {
        private OrdersDAL ordersDAL;

        public OrdersController()
        {
            ordersDAL = new OrdersDAL();
        }

        //sync call
        [HttpGet, Route("orders/{id}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetOrder(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                var order = ordersDAL.GetOrder(id);
                if (order == null)
                {
                    return RequestHelper.CreateResponse(Request, HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Order not found.");
                }

                return RequestHelper.CreateResponse(Request, HttpStatusCode.OK, order);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Error logging here
            }
        }       

        //async method call
        [HttpGet, Route("orders/{id}")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetOrder(string id)
        {
            try
            {
                var order = await ordersDAL.GetOrderAsync(id);
                if (order == null)
                {
                    return RequestHelper.CreateResponse(Request, HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Order not found.");
                }

                return RequestHelper.CreateResponse(Request, HttpStatusCode.OK, order);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Error logging here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use `Task.Run` from WebAPI (or other service frameworks) because that interferes with the ASP.NET thread pool heuristics.

Instead, use the naturally-asynchronous methods that are available in your WCF client proxy. (Side note: if the proxy is from a very old Visual Studio version, you may need to recreate it).

Then you can look at making your `SvcActivator` truly asynchronous. First, you'll need an asynchronous delegate type:

```
public delegate Task ServiceMethodAsync(T proxy);
```

Next, your `UseAsync` method:

```
public static async Task UseAsync(ServiceMethodAsync method, string url)
{
    var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>(binding);
    var endpoit = new EndpointAddress(url);
    IClientChannel proxy = (IClientChannel)channelFactory.CreateChannel(endpoit);
    bool success = false;

    try
    {
        await method((T)proxy);
        proxy.Close();
        success = true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (!success)
        {
            proxy.Abort();
        }
    }
}
```

Your DAL can use it as such:

```
public async Task<Order> GetOrderAsync(int id)
{
    Order order = null;
    await SvcActivator<IOrdersService>.UseAsync(async svc =>
    {
        order = await svc.GetOrderAsync(id);
    }, "url_goes_here");
    return order;
}
```

The end result is that you are using `async` all the way, rather than wrapping a synchronous WCF call (`GetOrder`) within a `Task.Run`.

Comment: Hi Stephen, thank you for your reply.
I've made change to the code, but it will not compile.

I am getting error `Cannot await 'void'` and it points to `await method((T)proxy);`

Comment: @303: Ensure that you're using `ServiceMethodAsync` as your argument type.

Comment: Duh! Missed that somehow. Thank you very much for your help!